# Extract text :after the last white space and that is in capital letters from last , ignoring dot(.)

Tags: python, sql-server, pandas

I have a text column, which basically has kind of notes, and most of the notes end with 2 to 3 capital letters after the last space in the text as in below 2 examples. And I need to extract those last characters which come after the last space into a new column either in pandas or in sql. And they should be extracted only if they are in capital letters, else null.

Ex 1 - 5723452309423 | NA | customer cancelled purchase| refund given | 12.3.2021 | approver is  **BG**

Ex 2 - 54986866 | NA | customer order returned| refund has been given | 12.4.2021 | **AKS**

Ex 3 - 54986866 | NA | customer order returned| refund has been given | 12.4.2021 | **KSR**.

Ex 4 - 54986866 | NA | customer order returned| refund has been given | 12.4.2021 | approved by **LS** and processed.**

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bsh3m.png)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oy03e.png)

Comment: You really need to consider storing your data properly. If the last portion of the string is important enough that you have to parse for it, it should be important enough to deserve its own column in the first place.

Comment: While asking a question, you need to provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example):
(1) DDL and sample data population, i.e. CREATE table(s) plus INSERT T-SQL statements. 
(2) What you need to do, i.e. logic and your code attempt implementation of it in T-SQL. 
(3) Desired output, based on the sample data in the #1 above.
(4) Your SQL Server version (SELECT @@version;).

Answer (score 2):

If those are just strings then you can use string.split(" ")[-1] to retrieve the last part.

```
my_str = "5723452309423 | NA | customer cancelled purchase| refund given | 12.3.2021 | approver is BG"
my_str.split(" ")[-1]
```

output is "BG" then you can use string.isupper() to check the case.

```
my_str.split(" ")[-1].isupper()
```

output is True

Answer (score 0):

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
    "col1": ["approver is BG", " AKS"]
})

df["col2"] = df["col1"].str.split(" ").str[-1]
```

df is:

```
          col1 col2
approver is BG   BG
           AKS  AKS
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a regex to explicitly select 2/3 upper case characters in the end:

```
df['new'] = df['note'].str.extract(r'([A-Z]{2,3}$)')
```

Or more generally for the last chunk [`rsplit`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.rsplit.html):

```
df['new'] = df['note'].str.rsplit('\s+', n=1).str[-1]
```

Answer (score 0):

your data in table

```
declare @a TABLE ( note varchar(max));
INSERT @a(note) VALUES
('5723452309423 | NA | customer cancelled purchase| refund given | 12.3.2021 | approver is BG'),
('54986866 | NA | customer order returned| refund has been given | 12.4.2021 | AKS'),
('58735980490 | NA | order cancelled refund requested| refund processed | 15.4.2021 |processed by : LO'),
('983943795803 | NA |_ refund asked by account owner| refunded')
```

In SQL you can use this query

```
select note,iif(lastValue = UPPER(lastValue) COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CS_AS,lastValue, null ) init1 from
(select note,right(rtrim(note),charindex(' ',reverse(rtrim(note))+' ')-1) lastValue from @a) b
```